# Минимизировать ущерб в случае проблем во время настройки sshd и фаерволла

Tags: ssh, ansible

Типичный плейбук у меня включает обычно конфигурирование фаервола и ssh:

```
- hosts: api
  roles:
    - sshd
    - apf
```

Для sshd просто копируется темплейт с нужным портом в **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**, где:

```
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port {{ ssh_port }}
```

После чего установка apf происходит, настройка **/etc/apf-firewall/allow_hosts.rules** и основного **/etc/apf-firewall/conf.apf**.
Как понимаете в **conf.apf**:

```
IG_TCP_CPORTS="{{ ssh_port }}"
```

Предпосылка: скажем у нас уже установлен sshd и apf и порт для ssh прописан `22`.

При реконфигурации (например хотим сменить порт на `222`) может статься так, что между настройкой sshd и настройкой apf что-то пойдёт не так.

В итоге ssh будет на `222` порту, но в apf будет открыт старый `22` порт. В итоге по ssh уже не присоединиться, придётся ребутить машину в recovery mod и ручками исправлять всё.

Данный пример я привёл так как сам столкнулся с подобным. Но и во многих других задачах при возникновении проблемы посередине выполнения **role** система в итоге останется в неконсистентом состоянии.

Как можно подобные вещи предотвратить или свести к минимуму ущерб?

Answer (score 3):

А что, если переходить постепенно?

1. apf – открыть порт 222.

   Если сломается после этого шага, у вас просто будет лишний открытый порт 222.
2. sshd –  переключиться на порт 222

   Если сломается здесь, то тоже останется лишний открытый 22, но по ssh вы уже сможете зайти на 222й.
3. apf – закрыть порт 222

Comment: Я к этому и вёл, для каждого кейса приходится очень много думать, чтоб предотвратить все кейсы. И когда ролей в плейбуке становится больше 8, сложно всё продумать. Поэтому и интересно более-менее общее решение.

Comment: @Suvitruf: подумаю завтра, как это правильно сделать. У вас же тут еще и роли совсем разные и независимые.

Comment: Здесь да. Но бывают таски, где роли связаны. api таск завязан на Java. Rethinkdb-client таск завязан на nodejs таск, к примеру.